# Use a wildcard in Python array?

Tags: python

Good day.
I can't seem to find a definitive answer to this question. I am attempting to decipher a large JSON file but I don't know the exact titles of the data and so I want to use a wildcard.

I have tried using ' [*] '  ' [] ' and anything else I can think of - no luck!

As it stands my code looks like this:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

pprint(data['Descriptions']['WILDCARD']['name'])
```

I am using python version 2.7.1 but also have 3.3. I may be doing this completely wrong...

Any help appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing.  You'll need to look at all of the items in `data['Descriptions'].values()` and check to

1. Make sure it's a dict.
2. Make sure it has a `'name'` field.

Once you've done those checks, you can pack it into a list.  here's a list-comprehension that should get the job done ... (I think :-)...

```
names = [d['name'] for d in data['Descriptions'].values()
         if isinstance(d, dict) and 'name' in d]
```

Comment: Ah, it all makes sense now. This worked a treat! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

`something[*].x` is implemented as `[item.x for item in something]`

**EDIT:**

The above is true if `something` is a `list`. For dictionaries, it is:

```
[item.x for item in something.values()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Im late to the party, but I would suggest not use *pprint* ever when using json objects or API calls.

Instead do something like ## print(json.dumps(data[key], indent=4)) ###